# Error: EACCES, open '/build/bundle.js' when running webpack

Tags: npm, webpack

Unable to run webpack from a subdirectory in my project.
This is the error I'm getting:
Error: EACCES, open '/build/bundle.js'

And this is the webpack configuration file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: ['./app.ts'],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: '/build'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js' ]
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts?sourceMap!ts-jsx' }
        ]
    }
};
```

Trying to use the command: 'sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm' didn't help.

Comment: I got it to work. I uninstalled all node modules and deleted the branch. Then I cloned and reinstalled the node modules with 'npm install'.

Answer (score 5):

A late answer, but it looks like you're trying to build in the root of the system (`/build`). For older versions of webpack use `./build` on the property *path*. For the latest version of webpack (3.0 as today) `path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),` should work.

Answer (score 3):

Webpack is trying to write to the /build directory. You do not seem to have permissions to write to it. You need to do `` sudo chown `whoami` /build `` in order to be able to write to it.